# Calabash - start_test_server_in_background not launching app

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

These are the steps I followed -

```
>Calabash-android console file.apk
irb(main):003:0>reinstall_apps
irb(main):004:0>start_test_server_in_background
nil
```

There is no error but my app is not launching. All I can see is a black screen like app is about to launch but its not. I tried replicating it on another test project but its working fine.

Comment: Can you open that app manually? @mjosh

Comment: yes I can open it manually and `calabash-android run file.apk` aslo working.

Comment: Do you have custom activity in the app?  If yes, use this command `MAIN_ACTIVITY="com.example.youractivity" calabash-android run file.apk`

Comment: `MAIN_ACTIVITY` is not recognized as external or internal command

Comment: Then use it like this `calabash-android run file.apk MAIN_ACTIVITY="com.example.youractivity" `

Comment: Can you please answer this so I mark it as a best answer

Comment: You need to run build command before running calabash run command, it will generate test server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any custom activity, use environment variable `MAIN_ACTIVITY` while using run command.

```
calabash-android console file.apk MAIN_ACTIVITY="com.example.youractivity"
```

**For more information**: http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/android/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html#MAIN_ACTIVITY